# Xamarin android AppCenter push messages when offline/app closed

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

We have started using the AppCenter push messaging. Have used the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/android
Works fine when the app is running in the foreground or in the background.

Messages sendt when app is closed of offline is not registered by the app. The app center responds with “202 Accepted”.

The AppCenter FAQ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/faq)

> If the app is offline, does the SDK store the logs and then send them
>   once it is back online?
>
> Yes. If the app is offline, the SDK will store up to 300 logs in
>   storage. Once the network connectivity is restored, the SDK will send
>   these logs to the App Center backend.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity.. My question : Is it possible to get the messages sendt 
to an offline/killed app, when the app comes online/starts ?